# How to stop Microsoft Word wavy green lines from blinking with each keystroke

Tags: microsoft-word

Word has this annoying behavior where if you dont tend to the green wavy lines in the beginning of a sentence, they will blink by appearing and reappearing with every keystroke. Ignoring the green wavy lines does not work.

Example:

[image]

How would you prevent the green wavy lines without disabling Word's grammar check feature?

Comment: What wavy green lines??

Comment: @Xavierjazz I have added a screenshot.